# deepcopy objects failed

Tags: python

I am new to the community and appreciate any response from you. I learned Python recently and tried to write a function to deep-copy some objects.

```
import copy
class node:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

a=node(8)
d=node(10)
c=copy.deepcopy(d)
def copyNode(a):
    c=copy.deepcopy(a)
copyNode(a)
print c.x
```

In above I try to use `copyNode` function to deep-copy node `a` to `c`. However, after calling this method the print out is 10, which means the function does not work. Any idea where I did wrong? Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643316/check-boolean-from-another-function/37643429#37643429

Comment: Variable scope. You assign to `c` within your function, **but that's not the same `c` as the one in the global scope.** You should `return` the copied object from your function and assign it there.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I add the global keyword and it works! Thank you again!

Comment: Don't use `global`, use `return`! `c = copyNode(a)`

Comment: @Cody You can add an answer and then accept it (after some time has passed) to help other users :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global scope variable unchanging in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668085/global-scope-variable-unchanging-in-python). (The problem isn't the deep copying)

Comment: Cody: in general you should avoid using the global keyword.  Of course it works, and it serves a purpose.  But, as your programs grow and your code becomes more sophisticated, the use of global variables (and mutable state) becomes increasingly risky and problematic.  For now, whenever you reach for "global" ... think about how you can wrap that state into an object class and consider using that.

Answer (score 0):

The variable c in `c=copy.deepcopy(a)` is defined locally inside the copyNode function. You see that when you print c.x there:

```
import copy
class node:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

a=node(8)
d=node(10)
c=copy.deepcopy(d)
def copyNode(a):
    c=copy.deepcopy(a)
    print(c.x)
print(c.x)
copyNode(a)
print(c.x)
```

output: `10 8 10`